# How to change the date format by storing the input in a variable in unix?

Tags: bash, date, unix

My Input is

```
./file \[10\/04\/16 01:02:03 BST\] \[06\/08\/16 05:02:08 BST\]
```

I want to convert `\[10\/04\/16 01:02:03 BST\]` to `Apr 10 16 01:02:03`

I am using the following code,

```
echo '\[10\/04\/16 01:02:03 BST\]' | awk -F'[][/: \\\\]+' 'BEGIN{split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",m,/ /)} {print m[$3+0],$2,$4,$5":"$6":"$7}'
```

Is it possible to extract the result by storing `\[10\/04\/16 01:02:03 BST\]` in a variable like `$StartTime` and use it in the code? Also now I am using only one date. Is it possible to use two dates?

Comment: Why are you escaping `/` and `[`, `]` etc?

Comment: I am escaping because if my input is stored in a variable, I have to use that variable in sort function where this `/` is needed. That is why I am escaping `/`, `[` `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this date conversion script called `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

mydt() {
   IFS='/' read -ra arr <<< "${1//[\[\]\\]}"
   TZ=':Europe/London' date -d "${arr[1]}/${arr[0]}/${arr[2]}" '+%b %d %y %T'
}

var1="$(mydt "$1")"
var2="$(mydt "$2")"

echo "$var1"
echo "$var2"
```

Then call it as:

```
bash script.sh '\[10\/04\/16 01:02:03 BST\]' '\[06\/08\/16 05:02:08 BST\]'
```

**Output:**

```
Apr 10 16 01:02:03
Aug 06 16 05:02:08
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It works fine. But instead of writing a function, can I store this function in a file and call that file in my input?

Comment: Yes definitely. Code between `for` and `done` can be placed in a file i.e. `mydt.sh` and Call it as `bash ./mydt.sh`

Comment: Could you Please explain me what is the use of `${dt//[\[\]\\]}`? Are we escaping the slashes and brackets? Is it possible to store the result in a variable and to get the output via `echo $variable1 and echo $variable2`?

Comment: `${dt//[\[\]\\]}` is to remove backslashes, `[` and `]` from original input. See updated answer for storing results in variables and keeping this code in a script file

Comment: Thanks but I am getting a slight differed answer. In the Time part, it is displaying as, `00:02:03` and  `04:02:08` instead of `01:02:03` `05:02:08`

Comment: You're getting `UTC/GMT` time instead of `BST`. [See this working demo](http://ideone.com/Q3yC67)

Comment: Can you send me some other link? The link is blocked in my organisation

Comment: All the code is available in this answer as well. If you can tell me any other online BASH editor available to you then I can copy/paste same code again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116080/discussion-between-vishwaroopa-and-anubhava).